# postgreSQL pl/python how do I get the RETURNING from a query?

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython, sql-returning

in this (vey condensed) query, how would one return the myfile_key from RETURNING?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction (src int, OUT result int) AS $$

plan = plpy.prepare("INSERT INTO myfile VALUES (nextval('seq_myfile'),$1,$2)
RETURNING myfile_key", ["integer","integer"] )

$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

(where the first field inserted is myfile_key)

The code doesn't return the value to output, and haven't been able to query it as a standard python result, as in:

```
result = rv[0]["myfile_key"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there is a call to `plpy.execute` missing in your code.  You are in principle right to access the `RETURNING` columns like `rv[0]["myfile_key"]`.  What's not working is the assignment to `OUT` parameters in PL/Python.  I suggest that you rewrite your function without `OUT` parameters using a normal `return` statement.

Comment: Hello Peter! and thanks for your comment. Yes, I'm moving over to trying to use standard return statements for this. I've been using return for lots of things already; I somehow assumed the SQL 'RETURNS' could also be used in this context.
(note: I _do_ have the call to plpy.execute; I was keeping this snippet as simple as possible!)

Comment: ... but one other thought: Don't we _need_ the OUT return int bit of the declaration to prevent:
ERROR:  function result type must be specified
???

Comment: Actually, `OUT` parameters work just fine with PL/Python. It's not the language that handles them, after all. What's not working in PL/Python before PostgreSQL 9.1 is multiple `OUT` parameters. But that's not what you're doing here. So you really should provide more details.